Exercise on holomorphic function
I am trying to do the following exercise on holomorphic functions:
"Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the whole complex plane, such that $|f(z)|\leq C|z|^k$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}-\bar B(0,1)$ (where $B(0,1)$ is the unit disk) for a certain $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial."
Since $f$ is holomorphic on the whole complex plane, my idea was to find a certain polynomial $P(z)$ such that the function $g(z)=f(z)-P(z)$ satisfies $\sup_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|g(z)|<+\infty$,so that I can apply Liouville's Theorem to conclude that $g(z)$ is constant, thus $f$ is a polynomial. For $z\in \bar B(0,1)$ there is no problem of course, due to Weierstrass' Theorem, but the problem is for $z\in \mathbb{C}-\bar B(0,1)$.
Is my idea correct? If not, can you give me any suggestion?
Thanks for any help!

You should definitely try to use Liouville's theorem but slightly differently. For Liouvelle's theorem you need to show that a certain function is entire and it's bounded by a constant. You have the equation $|f(z)|<C|z|^k.$ Isn't this screaming at you to do something?

I tried to consider the function $\frac{f(z)}{z^k}$, which is holomorphic and bounded outside the disk, but the problem is that it is not holomorphic at $z=0$

One way is to look at the coefficients of the Taylor series of $f$. They are given by $\oint f(z) dz/z^{k+1}$ - make the circle large to see that they are arbitrarily small and so must be zero.

@Steppenwolf Can you somehow modify the function to remove the singularity at $0$? Maybe try plugging in an actual polynomial for $f$ in case that gives you any ideas

You mean that the function $\frac{f(z)}{z^k}$ is extendable for continuity at $z=0$?

Maybe, I have to show that $f$ is identically zero in a small disk $B(0,\varepsilon)$, so that the function above is extendable for continuity at $z=0$?

@user8268 but then it would follow (since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected and $f$ holomorphic) that $f$ is identically zero. Moreover, I tried to prove what you say, but I have to use the fact that $f$ is continuous at the boundary of the disk $B(0,R)$, so there exists a constant $M$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M$. The problem is that this constant depends on $R$, so it is true that the circle is arbitrary, but I cannot conclude that the coefficients of the Taylor series are all 0.

Okk, not all the coefficients of the Taylor series are 0.

if $f(z)=P(z)+z^kg(z)$ with the degree of $P$ at most $k-1$ one has $|z^kg(z)| \le C_1|z|^k$ for large $|z|$  (with a larger $C_1$ and larger $|z|$) so $|g(z)| \le C_1, |z| \ge R_1$ hence $|g(z)| \le C_2$ for all $z$ hence $g$ constant hence $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$

hint: try Cauchy's Inequalities
